# Possible to displaying Arraylist of object's value in setListAdapter or SimpleAdapter for listview?

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist, android-arrayadapter

HI,

I would like to know if it is possible to display Arraylist of object's value in setListadapter or SimpleAdapter for listview?

String ArrayList works fine, I am just trying my luck with Object ArrayList

```
ArrayList<userinfo> list = new ArrayList<userinfo>();


setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<userinfo>(this, R.layout.messages, list)); // list.???


userinfo class consist of all the getters and setters.
```

String ArrayList(Working Version) @ 
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html

Answer (score 1):

Simplest solution is to implement userinfo.toString() method - then ArrayAdapter will automatically use this method to get string values from your objects. If you don't want to do that this way, you could overwrite ArrayAdapter.getView() method and create View objects manually.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible now just set your setLIstAdapter as an Object type.

> setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(),
>                             android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, userinfo));